# Is there any way to load a .png from my resources without using GDI+?

Tags: c++, winapi, wtl

I am trying to load a .png I stored in my projects resources, in order to set it in a picture control, but I can't quite figure out why. I did some research, and it seems like .png is not really supported with the usual LoadImage()-call.

However, I don't really want to convert it to a bitmap if I can get around it.

So far, I only found resources on how to do it with GDI+, or really ancient win32-api code.

Is there any way to load .png files natively by todays standard?

Comment: Not natively. I'd use OpenCV, can open bmp/jpg/png/tiff very easily.

Comment: GDI+ _is_ today's (well, yesterday's) standard.

Comment: @RyanP: The [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) offers PNG support through a [native codec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430027.aspx). So yes, this is very much supported natively.

Comment: @IInspectable Understood, missed the winapi tag. I was interpreting as native to C++.

Comment: begin how minimum from windows 7 (may be and vista) possible create `HICON` from `png` resource with [CreateIconFromResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648060(v=vs.85).aspx) after this can use it in [DrawIconEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648065.aspx) or get `HBITMAP` with [GetIconInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648070(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "new" way to do it would be Direct2D and WIC, which is demonstrated in the [Windows Imaging Component and Direct2D Image Viewer Win32 Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Imaging-Component-c5191dfc#content).

But if the rest of your application is basic controls, Direct2D is overkill.  The image has to be converted to a bitmap at some point to be displayed – whether in your GPU or in memory – and GDI+ fits this use case.

If these resources are icons or some other small-ish file (<2mp), I would reccomend embedding the resource as a bitmap.  You can keep your asset pipeline as PNG, just add a pre-build step to convert your PNGs to pre-multiplied BGRA bitmaps and use `LoadResource`.  There [are pre-built tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369649/how-to-convert-32-bit-bmp-to-contain-alpha-channel) to meet this need.

Comment: Is WIC not able to convert to an HBITMAP, thus avoiding the need for Direct2D? That sounds like an odd oversight...

Comment: None of the bitmap loading functions support alpha transparency for BMP files (even though the file format does). If you need alpha transparency, you'll have to go with PNG.

Comment: @andlabs, WIC can convert to a pixel buffer, from which you could create an `HBITMAP`, but no.

Comment: I'd consider that sufficient to say yes :S Your mileage may vary, I guess.

Comment: @IInspectable wait, was that in response to Mitch or to me? I never did fully understand `BI_PNG` or how GDI knows when to not clobber the alpha channel. Of course, the real question then is does the static control support transparency, since that's what it seems like the OP is using...

Comment: @andlabs, compare this to the WIC/Direct2D pipeline: You load an image using WIC, which copies the raw data (JPG/PNG/etc...) to GPU memory (assuming hardware accelerated rendering).  When you render it to a surface, the GPU decompresses the required portion of the image.  Nowhere during this operation do you require a full pixel buffer, rendering to one is purely an "export" of sorts.

Comment: @Mitch right, you have a point there. Of course that might not be too much for what the OP wants to do; it depends. But if both this and GDI+ aren't an option then I don't think they have any other options than a third party library...

Comment: @andlabs: That was in response to this answer's recommendation to store small images as bitmaps. Even if you store bitmaps with alpha channel, none of the bitmap loading APIs support reading the alpha channel. It's lost merely by choosing a file format other than PNG.

Comment: @IInspectable:  Yes, XP+ offers _some_ support for 32-bpp bitmaps with an alpha channel.  You have to get LoadImage to create a DIBSECTION, then you can use AlphaBlend or an ImageList with the right flags.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761389(v=vs.85).aspx#icons

Comment: @andlabs:  BI_PNG and BI_JPEG are for passing raw data to a printer that natively knows about the format.  You have to check if the printer supports it with a "printer escape" and then you can stuff the raw compessed data in where the pixel data normally goes and marshal it over of the printer in the guise of a BMP.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162843(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, exactly.  I guess my answer is a bit unclear on that, since presumably the question is relating to the STATIC control.